# Запятая "несмотря на то(,) что"

Tags: пунктуация

1. Вместе с тем, несмотря на то(,) что при составлении графика учитываются только пожелания участников,  на практике часто возникают вопросы.
2. В данной ситуации отказ работника уйти в отпуск в апреле, несмотря на то(,) что он запланирован графиком отпусков, будет обоснованным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вместе с тем, несмотря на то что при составлении графика учитываются только пожелания участников, на практике часто возникают вопросы.
2. В данной ситуации отказ работника уйти в отпуск в апреле, несмотря на то что он запланирован графиком отпусков, будет обоснованным.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Наречное выражение ВМЕСТЕ С ТЕМ не является вводным словом - оно имеет значение "одновременно, в то же время, также, притом". Получается, что в обоих предложениях придаточное предложение находится в середине СПП, а в этом случае составной союз однозначно не расчленяется.

Comment: На расчленение союза могут влиять  наречия, частицы, вводные слова, отнесенные к его МЕСТОИМЕННОЙ  части - в этом случае союз обязательно расчленяется: Вопросы задавали именно потому, что не всё было ясно. Вскоре после того, как часы пробили полночь, послышались торопливые шаги. Тетеревята не откликались на мой свист, вероятно, оттого, что я свистел неестественно. У союза НЕСМОТРЯ НА ТО ЧТО местоименная часть находится в конце, поэтому наречия, частицы, вводные слова к ней относиться не могут.

Answer (score 3):

Это сложный вопрос.

Основное правило звучит так: "Если придаточное предложение соединено  с главным при помощи сложного (составного) подчинительного союза, то запятая ставится один раз".
Однако поставновка запятой зависит от смысла и интонации, логического подчёркивания придаточного предложения и т.д.

Я бы посоветовала в первом предложении запятую поставить, а во втором - не ставить.
Но, повторяю, вопрос непростой.